# How to filter data for an attribute that is not part of the Datagrid object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid

I am trying to add a filter to my page but the column name I am trying to filter is not part of the object assigned to the Grid. It was dynamically added to the table results.

Given the object/model: `Car`

For example this:
`filter(:status, :enum, select: ['Good', 'Bad'])` works fine, as `:status` is an attribute of `Car`.

In the case of this `filter(:name, :enum, select: ['A1', 'A5'])` fails because `:name` is part of another object and not part of the `Car` object.
Of course this is just a sample object and adding :name is not an option for my real data model.

Query Error: `Car.name` `Undefined column name`.

Is there a way to filter a column of another object? I could not find anything in the documentation found here https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it, I mean, placing a filter-field unrelated to the Datagrid object, as follows. For an example model `Article`), I place an arbitrary user field, `max_per_page`, to (pass it to a pagination module).

**The key is** `:dummy => true` **option** in the *filter*.

In the Grid definition:

```rb
 /app/grids/articles_grid.rb
class ArticlesGrid < BaseGrid
  scope do
    Article
  end
  filter(:max_per_page, :integer, dummy: true)  ## <= Key!!
  column(:content, mandatory: true)
end
```

In your model controller:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @grid = ArticlesGrid.new(grid_params) do |scope|
      maxval = grid_params[:max_per_page].to_i  ## <= How to fetch it.
      scope.page(params[:page]).per(maxval)
    end
  end

  private
    def grid_params
      params.fetch(:articles_grid, {}).permit!
    end
end
```

An example in the [official doc](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Filters#filter-block) includes the option, but there is no description, unfortunately……
Or, in the source code annotation [Datagrid RDoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bogdan/datagrid/Datagrid%2FFilters%2FClassMethods:filter).